# Inheritance of of abstract classes

Tags: inheritance, diagram

In the following diagram, `AbstractPainter` is an abstract class which implements `IPainter`. `ContemporaryPainter` and `PastPainter` are classes that extend `AbstractPainter`. Taking this into account, do `PastPainter` and `AbstractPainter` extend `IPainter`? Or do they only extend `AbstractPainter`?

Thanks![image: Diagram]

Comment: There's a distinct lack of a diagram here.

Comment: for some reason the picture of the diagram didn't show: [link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zGHoE.png)

Answer (score 2):

They only extend `AbstractPainter`. They do implement `IPainter`. So you could do

```
IPainter painter = new PastPainter();
AbstractPainter otherPainter = new ContemporaryPainter();
```

And it would still be valid.

However, when referencing them in a collection, like

```
List<? extends IPainter> list = new ...
```

it still uses the word "extends". You still don't call it "extending the interface" though.

The only "extends the interface" would be if you made something like the following snippet:

```
public interface IPolymath extends IPainter {
    List<String> getOtherProfessions();
}
```

Where some other interface extends the original interface.

Comment: Thanks, that's great help! But what if, for example, I want to implement a generic method about a generic type of painter? Do I use <T extends IPainter> or <T extends AbstractPainter>?

Comment: You could do it with either one. If you had other `IPainter`s, and you want to include those too, then use `T extends IPainter`. If you want to exclude those, use `AbstractPainter`. If you don't have, and never will have, any others, then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the correct way to think about it would be that they extend the abstract class and implement the interface.

For example, a `LinkedList` implements the `List` interface and the `AbstractSequentialList`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `PastPainter` and `ContemporaryPainter` are of type `IPainter` since they extend `AbstractPainter` which implements `IPainter`.

For instance: Assume `ClassA` either implements or extends `ClassB`. And then if `ClassC` extends/implements `ClassA` then automatically `ClassC` is also type of `ClassB`.

Any subclass is of type its Superclass is and also is of type which its Superclass is inherited from.

Answer (score 0):

From the semantic point of view, interface and abtract class from you example are redundant. Definition of abstract class would be enought. But, clear UML complying answer to your question is that, AsbtractPainter does not implement interface IPainter directly, but instances of classes which specialize you abstract class and are not abstract do. It is also important to define, that specialized classes can substitute general one.